# Formatting a date

Tags: iphone, date

**Edit: Updating post based on Martins comments below**

Hello,

I'm just trying to get a date from a string, my code is as follows:

```
NSString *strStartDateTime = [startTimeArray objectAtIndex:i];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];               
NSDate *dtStartDateTime;
dtStartDateTime = [formatter dateFromString: strStartDateTime];
```

strStartDateTime has a value of '2010-09-30 15:23:30', but this code returns a value of '2010-09-30 14:23:30 GMT', all I want is '2010-09-30 15:23:30' as per the string.

Is it taking Day light Savings Time into consideration. This is very frustrating, I simply want to convert the NSString to NSDate and its changing the value.

Regards,
Stephen

Comment: "hh" gives 12-hour clock hours, if you use that you will need to include am/pm - %a.

Comment: It **IS** the same. You're probably in time zone GMT+1, so 14:23:30 GMT is the same as 15:23:30 local time. When you later convert the date back to a string, you can decide what timezone to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite understand your question. What do you mean by "it gives me the GMT value"? What is your input? What is your expected output?

If you have problems with time zone conversions, you could try to set the time zone for the formatter:

```
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
```

or

```
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
```

As I said, it all depends on what the input and expected output is.

EDIT:

You actually don't have a problem. The date is parsed correctly. You can verify it this way:

```
NSString *strStartDateTime = [startTimeArray objectAtIndex:i];

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];  

NSDate *dtStartDateTime = [formatter dateFromString: strStartDateTime];
NSString *parsedDateAsString = [formatter stringFromDate:dtSTartTime];

// parsedDateAsString will have the correct value
```

Comment: Thanks Philippe, the line [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]]; solved.